# symfony2: form does not submit all values properly

Tags: php, forms, symfony

When submitting the form below, the field 'Body' which is a textarea, is not mapped to the $message object when  `$form->getData();` is called.

I can see in $request.parameters that there are two values:

-form, which is an array containing the values of the form, but the textarea value is missing.

-Body, which is a string containing the value of the textarea.

Why is Body not part of the form object ?

1. controller action :

   ```
   class ContactController extends Controller {

   public function indexAction(Request $request) {
     $message = new Message();

     $form = $this->createFormBuilder($message)
           ->add('Name', 'text', array('required' => true))
           ->add('Email', 'email')
           ->add('Subject', 'text')
           ->add('Body', 'textarea')
           ->getForm();

     $form->handleRequest($request);

      if ($form->isValid()) {
       // data is an array with "name", "email", and "message" keys
       $data = $form->getData();
      }

      return $this->render('PhotographPhotoBundle:Contact:index.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }
   }
   ```
2. Message class:

   ```
   class Message
   {
      protected $name;
      protected $subject;
      protected $body;
      protected $email;
      + setters and getters here
   }
   ```
3. form template

   ```
    {# src/Photograph/PhotoBundle/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig #}

     {% block field_row %}
      {% spaceless %}
       {{ form_errors(form) }}
       {{ form_widget(form) }}
      {% endspaceless %}
     {% endblock field_row %}

    {% block email_widget %}
       <input type="email" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} value="{{ value }}" class="field-email   form_field">       
    {% endblock %}

     {% block text_widget %}
       <input type="text" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} value="{{ value }}" class="field-name form_field">
     {% endblock %}

     {% block textarea_widget %}
       <textarea name="field-message" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}  cols="45" rows="5"  class="field-message form_field">{{ value }}</textarea>
     {% endblock %}
   ```
4. the form view

   ```
        <form action="{{ path('PhotographPhotoBundle_contact') }}" method="post" class="feedback_form" >

                                   {{ form_errors(form) }}                                       

                                   {{ form_widget(form.Name) }}
                                           <div class="clear"></div>
                                   {{ form_widget(form.Email, { 'attr': {'placeholder': 'email' }}) }}
                                           <div class="clear"></div>
                                   {{ form_widget(form.Subject, { 'attr': {'placeholder': 'sujet' }}) }}
                                           <div class="clear"></div>
                                   {{ form_widget(form.Body, { 'attr': {'placeholder': 'message' }}) }}
                                           <div class="clear"></div>    
                                   <input value="envoyer votre message" type="submit"  class="feedback_go" />
                                           <div class="ajaxanswer"></div>
                                      {{ form_end(form) }}
   ```

Comment: Verify getBody/setBody are properly defined.  It might be a case sensitive issue I suppose.  Try ->add('body', 'textarea') but doubtful.  Otherwise, change textarea to text.  If text works then once again you have a template issue.  The fact that you have a name attribute in your textarea template is a bit suspicious.

Comment: yes, it seems to be related to textarea because if I change it to text, it works. I wonder what the problem is....

Comment: actually you were right, it's the name attribute that was causing issue. I took it out and it's fine now. Please answer the question so I can mark it as answer. You've only commented here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
{% block textarea_widget %}
    <textarea name="field-message" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}  cols="45" rows="5"  class="field-message form_field">{{ value }}</textarea>
{% endblock %}
```

Should be:

```
{% block textarea_widget %}
    <textarea {{ block('widget_attributes') }}  cols="45" rows="5"  class="field-message form_field">{{ value }}</textarea>
{% endblock %}
```

In other words, drop the name attribute.  First time I ever successfully debugged one of these templates!

Answer (score 1):

The first `parameter` of the `FormBuilder::add()` method is the name of that field. It is supposed to match the property of your class. I'm not quite sure why it is only not working for the `Body` part. Change the form type to this:

```
  $form = $this->createFormBuilder($message)
    ->add('name', 'text', array('required' => true))
    ->add('email', 'email')
    ->add('subject', 'text')
    ->add('body', 'textarea')
    ->getForm();
```

Note the lower-case letters so they match your entity. If you want to change the label of a field you can either set it in the `config` array:

```
    ->add('body', 'textarea', array(
         'attributes' => array(
              'label' => 'Body'
         )
      )
    )
```

Or just change your template correctly:

```
<label>Body</label>
{{ form_widget(form.Body, { 'attr': {'placeholder': 'message' }}) }}
```

See [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming) for a more clear explanation.

Comment: thanks, but I've changed the first parameters to lower case so they match properties in the class and I've changed it in the view too. But with no luck. It works only if I change textarea to text.